# Fixing python not recognized within VisualStudio Code even after Python Install

Tags: python

In downloading and setting up python I was experiencing this issue:
**"Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available."** And I followed advice from [this post on SSL error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54135206/requests-caused-by-sslerrorcant-connect-to-https-url-because-the-ssl-module). I had tried those solutions, but my issue is that Anaconda had not fully downloaded. In Downloading Anaconda I somehow deleted Python and now in my VS Code my .py files aren't recognized. I reinstalled Python but it seems that I have multiple unfinished versions of python which is why my **files are still not recognized**. Anyone know how to fix this issue?

Comment: Do you have the python extension installed in VSCode? Can you try to run python in the VSCode Terminal?

Comment: Here's what I got: 
The term 'C:/Users/y77593/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, 
script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try       
again.
At line:1 char:3
+ & C:/Users/y77593/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe " ...
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:/Users/y77593...on39/python.exe:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: How did you run this? Did you try to use "Python3", or did you manually put this path?

Comment: I ran that in VS Code with the > triangular Play button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution demanded that I

1. find all Python version of which there were a few in different places on my drive and purge them. [This resource helped.](https://www.educative.io/edpresso/how-to-uninstall-python)
2. Redownload Python. [This helped.](https://medium.com/co-learning-lounge/how-to-download-install-python-on-windows-2021-44a707994013)
3. Update VS Code [Following this Guide.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60807557/how-to-update-vs-code-on-windows)